# Are there any Vulcan Battlecruisers shown in canonical Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

The Star Trek Universe rarely shows Vulcan ships, and when they do, they usually don't seem to be that powerful. The Federation, Romulans, Klingons, Borg, Cardassians, Dominion, etc. all seem to have ships that are designed for battle. They had to have had their own fleet before they became a member of the Federation. We usually see Vulcan ships as science and exploration ships, and they didn't seem to be heavily armed. Why do Vulcans, as an advanced species, have such a small fleet onscreen, and why didn't see see them in the *TNG* era after they joined the Federation?

Comment: I know that Vulcan ships can be large, and they aren't weak and weaponless, but they've never seemed to be a major power.

Comment: are you asking whether the Vulcans have warships or if they use warships?

Comment: Do you mean the 22nd Century where the Vulcans are their own power or 24th centuary vulcan ship where vulcan is a federation member?

Comment: keep in mind - the Vulcan's are part of the United Federation of Planets, so any larger "Vulcan" ship would be a federation starship.  In Enterprise (pre-Federation), you do see Vulcan Battleships

Comment: @psubsee2003 where in enterprise are there Vulcan Battleships

Comment: @BenjaminErickson been a while since i've watched Enterprised, but i do recall Archer and others referring to some of the larger ships are "Battlecruisers" or maybe similar name.  I'd have to try to find the reference

Comment: @ Benjamin Erickson I'm asking if they have and/or use battleships.

Comment: I haven't really thought of it, but it has to be right before they joined the Federation, if they were making their own type of ships before that.

Comment: Vulcan ships have an interesting design, like the ones with the rings, but I haven't seen any of those with heavy armaments.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge just because they haven't been shown dosen't mean they aren't there.

Comment: Then...I'll just have to use my imagination? I was just wondering if they've ever been shown onscreen or even mentioned.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge good point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Vulcans have at least one canonically seen combat vessel: the [D'kyr class "combat cruiser"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/D%27kyr_type). It's both well-shielded and well-armed as well as being quite nippy.

> **ARCHER:** *Take a look at your long-range sensors. There's a Vulcan combat cruiser a few million kilometres from here. Unless you want to upset them, I suggest you turn around.*
>
> <sub><sup>[ENT: Future Tense](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/42.htm)</sup></sub>

This class of vessel is referred to in the scripts as being a

> powerful-looking Vulcan ship[s]

---

In the Extended Universe, we encounter an even more formidable Vulcan ship, the ShRaan-class, described as being even more powerful than their combat cruisers.

> Dropping out of warp were two more DKyr-type combat cruisers, and **one of the larger, better-armed ShRaan-class ships, which looked like a spear jammed through a hoop.** The weaponry the newcomers carried between them would be more than enough to blow both Columbia and the remnants of the cargo fleet to little more than drifting trails of vapor in a few seconds, polarized hull plating notwithstanding.
>
> <sub><sup>[Enterprise: Kobiyashi Maru](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_(novel))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are asking about the TOS/TNG era, the Vulcans are a Federation member and don't have their own warships just like Earth doesn't have its own warships.

The Vulcan ships that we do encounter are generally civilian or science vessels.   While it may appear that most Federation ships are human-dominated, we do sometimes encounter Federation ships that are primilary manned by Vulcans, such as [TOS era Intrepid](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Intrepid_(NCC-1631)).

In short, this is sort of like asking why California doesn't have battleships.

Comment: this is a good answer but what about the 22nd Century

Comment: @ ThePopMachine I understand, but California doesn't house a different humanoid species, isn't a planet, and didn't come into contact with Earth after WW 3.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge before it became part of the USA, Texas had their own [Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Navy).  Pre-Federation, Vulcan would have had their own independent equivalent to Starfleet.  But once they joined, their defensive fleet was probably absorbed into starfleet.  I think you need to clarify your question a bit as to what you might be looking for in terms of timeline

Comment: Okay. I will edit it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yet there were Vulcan ships in Unification part II and mention of Tellarite freighters in ds9

Comment: There's at least 1 Federation ship that had an all Vulcan crew, it was the DS9 episode where the Vulcan goes crazy and starts killing people. Another DS9 episode is where the crew play baseball against a team from an all Vulcan ship

Comment: @MarkusRutledge:    For the purpose of the analogy, I meant it's like asking why California doesn't have warships **today**.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I see. I haven't watched Star Trek: Enterprise--just TNG, VOY, DISC, PIC, and a couple of OS episodes, so I probably haven't heard references towards Vulcan ships.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge:   As SpacePheonix points out, then appeared fairly prominently in DS9.   It seems like you have been avoiding Vulcans,  xenophobe.

Comment: @MarkusRutledge Besides Voyager, enterprise to me if the best series, you should try it.

Comment: some states do have Navies - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Guard#Naval_Militia (NY, and Alaska as well) ;)

Comment: @ThePopMachine You should go to the Mirror Universe. You could be their xenophobic, cold, I.S.S. Cheron commanding Emperor that kills his own guards regularly and in mass amounts with a self-flying shuriken. (That's not personal. It's just from ST Discovery. XD)

Comment: @Benjamin Erickson I'll think about watching Enterprise on Netflix.

Comment: And good to know about the navies NK Campbell. Do you have experience with it?